# How can I click a checkbox and know if checked or not checked?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, checked, unchecked

```js
$('.p_check').click(function() {
          if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
              alert("checked");
          } else {
               alert("unchecked");
          }
       });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='checkbox p_check'><label><input type='checkbox'>New Password</label></div>
```

My alert is always "unchecked", no matter if I check or uncheck it

Comment: `$('.p_check')` is a `<div>`. Why would you expect that to be checked?

Comment: Also once you fix your incorrect selector, you don't have to do `$(this).is(':checked')`  Just use `this.checked` and avoid jQuery for that property access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using div as element for checking, but you should use checkbox:

```
$('.p_check').click(function() {
var cb =    $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]');
          if (cb.is(':checked')) {
              alert("checked");
          } else {
               alert("unchecked");
          }
       });
```

Comment: Or target the checkbox instead?  Rather than fixing the incorrect selector for the binding?

Comment: yes, I put the class to the wrong element, my fault